# Error al abrir un .exe generado con visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, wpf

realicé hace unos días una aplicación de escritorio con C# y WPF, generé el ejecutable mediante un tutorial que ví, en el cual lo generaban  dentro del visual studio en Build- Build Mudando(Mudando es el nombre de la aplicación). El ejecutable se generó correctamente pero al hacer algunos cambios en el diseño de la aplicación y volver a generar el ejecutable, en algunas pc donde ya había probado el ejucatble me sale el siguiente error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obviamente lo solucioné instalado lo que me dice la alerta, pero quisiera saber si es posible que el ejecutable no me pida ese archivo, como paso la primera vez que lo generé o si es normal que esto pase.

Comment: Cuando vas a crear el `.exe` una de las opciones es instalar los paquetes necesarios (o algo paregido) desde ahí, seleccionas los que hagan falta

Comment: hola y gracias por responder, trataré de volver a generarlo, pero hasta ahora no me ha salido esas opciones de las que me hablas

Comment: Finalmente lo he vuelto a generar y no me salen las opciones,ademas sigo teneiendo el mismo problema

Answer (score 1):

Eso es un **REQUISITO PREVIO**, y Visual Studio te da la opción de Publicar tu programa incluyendo las instrucciones de que, en caso de que ese requisito no se cumpla, descargue el componente necesario para que lo haga, en tu caso el .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Para eso debes ir a **Proyecto** -> **Propiedades de (tu proyecto)** -> **Publicar** -> **Requisitos Previos** y ahí se abrirán la lista de componentes disponibles, marcas lo que tu software requiere y le das aceptar, una vez lo publiques y trates de iniciarlo, el propio instalador verificará que el componente requerido esté disponible y en caso de no estar, lo descargará de la fuente oficial.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias me fue de mucha ayuda